# Android : Delete country code from contact

Tags: android, contacts, telephony

How can i delete or detect the country codes of contact numbers efficiently ?

> +213231756 will be 231756 (+231 is the country code of Algeria)
>
> +880171876809 will be 0171876809(+88 is the country code of BD)

Say for example: i create a string.xml file like

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
<item>93,AF</item> 
<item>355,AL</item>
<item>213,DZ</item>
```

And there are almost 190+ country codes in xml . 
and check every contact number with the string array isn't time efficient.

> Is there any efficient solution to detect the country code of a  list of phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "libphonenumber.jar" for this. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/7.3.1/

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    // phone must begin with '+'
    PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phone, "");
    int countryCode = numberProto.getCountryCode();
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```